# Codeigniter Controller cannot get the input post values

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post, input, codeigniter-2

Hy, I have problem with codeigniter. My controller can't get the values from my view. Here is the code

Controller

```
 public function konfirmasi_pembayaran() {

 $data['data_penumpang_bayi'] = $this->input->post("data_penumpang_bayi");

if($data['data_penumpang_bayi'] > 0){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['data_penumpang_bayi']; $i++) {
        $data['ortu_bayi'. $i] = $this->input->post("ortu_bayi". $i);
        $data['nationality_bayi'. $i] = $this->input->post("nationalitybayi". $i);
        $data['name_bayi' . $i] = $this->input->post("namebayi" . $i);
        $data['titel_bayi' . $i] = $this->input->post("titelbayi" . $i);
        $data['lastname_bayi' . $i] = $this->input->post("lastnamebayi" . $i);
        $data['date_birth_bayi' . $i] = $this->input->post("datebirthbayi" . $i);
    }
}
     $this->load->view("flight/konfirmasi_pembayaran_page", $data);
}
```

View

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Titel<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="span6 m-wrap" name="titelbayi<?php echo $i ?>">
            <option value="">Pilih Titel...</option>
            <?php foreach ($json_data->required->titlei1->resource as $value) {
                ?>                        
                <option value="<?php echo $value->id ?>"><?php echo $value->name ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nama Depan<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="" name="namebayi<?php echo $i ?>" data-required="1" class="span6 m-wrap"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="data_penumpang_bayi" value="<?php echo $data_penumpang_bayi ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nama Belakang<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="" name="lastnamebayi<?php echo $i ?>" data-required="1" class="span6 m-wrap"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Tanggal Lahir<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="date_birth"  placeholder="(ex.1970-10-10)"  data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="datebirthbayi<?php echo $i ?>" class="m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker" size="16" type="text" value="" />

    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kewarganegaraan<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="span6 chosen-with-diselect" name="nationalitybayi<?php echo $i ?>">
            <option value="">Pilih Kewarganegaraan...</option>
            <?php
            $contents = file_get_contents('https://api.master18.tiket.com/general_api/listCountry?output=json&token=' . $token . '');
            $data = json_decode($contents);
            foreach ($data->listCountry as $key) {
                ?>
                <option <?php if ($key->country_id == "id") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $key->country_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->country_id; ?>, <?php echo $key->country_name; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller code cannot get the values from previous view. What's wrong with my code ?
Any answer will be really appreciated. Sorry for my bad english

Thank you.

Comment: Your bad english is forgiven. Your very bad code is not.

Comment: done. sorry. this is my first time

Comment: I cannot post all my controller function because it is too long to posted here. so, I just can give the error code. the code that I posted cannot get the values. what's wrong with that code ?

Comment: am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

In your html code example, there is no form and no submit button. How are you posting ?

the concept in codeigniter (or any other MVC frameworks) for filling in a form, submit the form and get a resultpage is:

1. create a view page with form and submit button.
2. The submit button's action calls your controller function
3. in the controller function you can do something with your POST data
4. send back $data with `$this->load->view('your_view',$data')`

you can find a tutorial here (skip the validation part): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#tutorial

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I have form and submit button in my project. In this case, I just give the error code. I've tried to send back data with $this->load->view("myview",$data) to debug and display nothing. Thanks @vickel